# Trying to convert bunch of jpegs into a movie

Tags: video, encoding

I have 28,000 images I need to convert into a movie.
I tried

```
mencoder mf://*.jpg -mf w=640:h=480:fps=30:type=jpg -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=msmpeg4v2 -nosound -o ../output-msmpeg4v2.avi
```

But it seems to crap out at 7500 frames.

The files are named
webcam_2007-04-16_070804.jpg
webcam_2007-04-16_071004.jpg
webcam_2007-04-16_071204.jpg
webcam_2007-04-16_071404.jpg
Up to march 2008 or so.

Is there another way I can pass the filenames to mencoder so it doesn't stop part way?

```
MEncoder 2:1.0~rc2-0ubuntu13 (C) 2000-2007 MPlayer Team
CPU: Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.40GHz (Family: 15, Model: 2, Stepping: 7)
CPUflags: Type: 15 MMX: 1 MMX2: 1 3DNow: 0 3DNow2: 0 SSE: 1 SSE2: 1
Compiled with runtime CPU detection.
success: format: 16  data: 0x0 - 0x0
MF file format detected.
[mf] search expr: *.jpg
[mf] number of files: 28617 (114468)
VIDEO:  [IJPG]  640x480  24bpp  30.000 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
[V] filefmt:16  fourcc:0x47504A49  size:640x480  fps:30.00  ftime:=0.0333
Opening video filter: [expand osd=1]
Expand: -1 x -1, -1 ; -1, osd: 1, aspect: 0.000000, round: 1
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
Selected video codec: [ffmjpeg] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MJPEG decoder)
==========================================================================
VDec: vo config request - 640 x 480 (preferred colorspace: Planar YV12)
VDec: using Planar YV12 as output csp (no 3)
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
videocodec: libavcodec (640x480 fourcc=3234504d [MP42])
Writing header...
ODML: Aspect information not (yet?) available or unspecified, not writing vprp header.
Writing header...
ODML: Aspect information not (yet?) available or unspecified, not writing vprp header.
Pos: 251.3s   7539f ( 0%) 47.56fps Trem:   0min   0mb  A-V:0.000 [1202:0]
Flushing video frames.
Writing index...
Writing header...
ODML: Aspect information not (yet?) available or unspecified, not writing vprp header.

Video stream: 1202.480 kbit/s  (150310 B/s)  size: 37772908 bytes  251.300 secs  7539     frames
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shove the list of images in a file, one per line. Then use `mf://@filename`

Comment: mencoder mf://@../test.txt -mf w=640:h=480:fps=30:type=jpg -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=msmpeg4v2 -nosound -o ../output-msmpeg4v2.avi

Still stops at 7500 or so files....even though they are all in the test file.

Comment: Check the 7500whateverth JPEG to see if there's anything odd about it?

Comment: Looks like that fixed things. I just deleted a couple of files from the text listing around that area. It got stuck on 9600 this time. Time to do some more deleting.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off going to #mplayer or #ffmpeg on Freenode IRC for specific help with those programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a video from a sequence of images using LiVES:
http://lives.sourceforge.net

Simply place all of the images in a directory, and make sure they are in alphanumeric order.
Then in LiVES, just go to File/Open File or Directory, and double-click on the image directory.

Once the images have loaded you can edit the clip and save it in a variety of formats.

Answer (score 0):

another alternative is to bypass mencoder and use ffmpeg directly

Answer (score 0):

Kinda of an odd answer... but I thought that Blender could construct videos from sequences of images. Just a thought.